# jQuery mobile image centered in header with "default" size

Tags: jquery, css

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pmjtf/

I'm trying to get the logo image to be immediately to the left of the header "text".

I also want the image to be the same size as the default header text which I think is ~16px. More precisely, I do not want the header bar to resize because of the large image, I want the image to shrink.

I've been able to force the sizing using the `height` tag, but cannot get the center alignment.

```
<div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
              <img src="example.png"> <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to put your image within that `<h1>` and set its size to `1em`, which makes it automatically scale to whatever the text size is.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <h1>
      <img src="example.png" style="height: 1em" />
      test
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```